How to open PWA minimized on startup? (Windows, Edge)
I want a Progressive Web App to start minimized on startup. I use Edge on Windows.
Bonus points if it can minimize to system tray.
Is there a way to set this up?
Is it possible using other browsers?
My specific use case is Youtube Music. They didn't make a desktop app, so Im using the PWA.
